# C++ Multiple sets of variadic function arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to optimize a very low level and widely used function in an compute intensive application. 
Let's say I have the following type :

```
template<typename T, int N> 
class Elem {...};
```

I'd like to write a function that could be called such as :

```
template<typename T, int N>
void func(const Elem<T, N> & ... /*N elements*/, Elem<T, N> & ... /* N elements*/)
```

I'm looking for a approach for which I can be sure that the compilers will be able to remove any temporary introduced by the function signature.

The elements will typically be elements taken from different places of a vector/array. E.g. :

```
Elem<float, 3> inputs[10];
Elem<float, 3> outputs[10];
...
func(input[4], input[2], input[9], output[6], output[8], output[1]);
```

The answer might be initializer lists but I fear it might have some overhead...

NB : indirection indexes above are all compile-time computed function and are in short ranges.

---

EDIT

In fact, what I'd like would be something like :

```
template<typename... T, int N>
void func(const Elem<T, N>&... inputs, const Elem<T, N>&... outputs)
{
  static_assert(sizeof...(inputs) == N, "invalid number of arguments");
  static_assert(sizeof...(outputs) == N, "invalid number of arguments");
  static_assert(std::is_same<std::integral_constant<int N>...>::value, "invalid arguments");
}
```

But I can't have this code to compile on VS2017.
Answer can be C++17.

Comment: Stop fearing overhead and start measuring it.

Comment: what temporaries do you fear? I see only references as parameters

Comment: How about `void func(const Elem<T, N> &input, Elem<T, N> &output);` with `func({input[4], input[2], input[9]}, {output[6], output[8], output[1]});`? Assuming `Elem` is implemented appropriately this should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to write a function that could be called such as :

```
template<typename T, int N>
void func(const Elem<T, N> & ... /*N elements*/, 
          Elem<T, N> & ... /* N elements*/)
```

As far I know, what you ask isn't easy to express with the available language.

The best I can imagine, is write the `func()` function as follows

```
template <typename ... Es>
typename std::enable_if<checkElems<Es...>::value>::type
   func (Es & ... es)
 {
   using type = typename checkElems<Es ...>::type;   // former T

   constexpr std::size_t num { sizeof...(Es) >> 1 }; // former N

   // ...
 }
```

Where `func()` receives a list (`Es & ... es`) of arguments and the function is SFINAE enabled only if the relative list of types (`Es ...`) satisfy a list of requirements that are implemented in the custom type-traits `checkElems` (see the following example).

So the following `checkElems` check that:

- there is at least an argument type
- the first argument is in the form `Elem<T, N> const`
- the number of argument type is exactly `2 * N`
- the first `N` types are equal to each other
- the following `N` types are equal to each other
- adding `const` the following `N` types, they are equal to the first `N`
- without adding `const`, the following `N` types are different to the first `N`

Inside `func()` you're able to use `type` (see example), that is the `T` type in `Elem<T, N>`, and `num`, that is the `N` value in `Elem<T, N>`.

You can do this checks but I don't know if it's a good idea.

A compilable example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, std::size_t N> 
struct Elem {};

template <typename>
struct extrElem;

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct extrElem<Elem<T, N> const>
 {
   using type = T;

   static constexpr std::size_t num { N };
 };

template <std::size_t, std::size_t, typename ...>
struct extrTypes;

template <std::size_t Skip, std::size_t Num, typename ... Es, typename T0,
          typename ... Ts>
struct extrTypes<Skip, Num, std::tuple<Es...>, T0, Ts...>
 { using type = typename extrTypes<
      Skip-1U, Num, std::tuple<Es...>, Ts...>::type; };

template <std::size_t Num, typename ... Es, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct extrTypes<0U, Num, std::tuple<Es...>, T0, Ts...>
 { using type = typename extrTypes<
      0U, Num-1U, std::tuple<Es..., T0>, Ts...>::type; };

template <typename ... Es, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct extrTypes<0U, 0U, std::tuple<Es...>, T0, Ts...>
 { using type = std::tuple<Es...>; };

template <typename ... Es>
struct extrTypes<0U, 0U, std::tuple<Es...>>
 { using type = std::tuple<Es...>; };

template <typename>
struct sameContTypes : public std::false_type
 { };

template <template <typename ...> class C, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct sameContTypes<C<T0, Ts...>>
   : public std::is_same<C<T0, Ts...>, C<Ts..., T0>>
 { };

template <typename E0, typename ... Es>
struct checkElems
 {
   static constexpr std::size_t num { extrElem<E0>::num };

   using type = typename extrElem<E0>::type;
   using lt1 = typename extrTypes<0U, num, std::tuple<>, E0, Es...>::type;
   using lt2 = typename extrTypes<num, num, std::tuple<>, E0, Es...>::type;

   static constexpr bool value {
         ( (num << 1) == 1U + sizeof...(Es) )
      && sameContTypes<lt1>::value
      && sameContTypes<lt2>::value
      && (true == std::is_same<E0,
             typename std::tuple_element<0U, lt2>::type const>::value)
      && (false == std::is_same<E0,
             typename std::tuple_element<0U, lt2>::type>::value) };
 };

template <typename ... Es>
typename std::enable_if<checkElems<Es...>::value>::type
   func (Es & ... es)
 {
   using type = typename checkElems<Es ...>::type;   // former T

   constexpr std::size_t num { sizeof...(Es) >> 1 }; // former N

   // ...
 }

int main()
 {
   Elem<int, 3>        ei3;
   Elem<int, 4>        ei4;
   Elem<int, 3> const  eci3;
   Elem<int, 4> const  eci4;

   func(eci3, eci3, eci3, ei3, ei3, ei3);    // compile
   //func(eci3, eci3, eci3, ei3, eci3, ei3); // compilation error
   //func(eci3, eci3, eci3, ei3, ei3, ei4); // compilation error
   //func(eci3, eci3, eci4, ei3, ei3, ei3); // compilation error
   //func(eci4, eci4, eci4, ei4, ei4, ei4); // compilation error
   //func(eci4, eci4, eci4, eci4, ei4, ei4, ei4); // compilation error
   func(eci4, eci4, eci4, eci4, ei4, ei4, ei4, ei4); // compile
 }
```

Comment: Wow ! That's impressive !
I'll try to extend the  extrTypes approach to split the actual arguments in two sets.

Answer (score 3):

I would pass each set as a tuple of references, which you can make with `std::tie`.

In most cases there will be no overhead at all as the compiler will see through all the tuple construction.

example:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>


template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct Elem {
    T value() const { return val; }

    T val;
};

Elem<float, 3> input[10];
Elem<float, 3> output[10];


namespace detail {
    template<typename T, typename F, std::size_t... Is>
    constexpr auto tuple_foreach(T&& tup, F& f, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        using expand = int[];
        void(expand{0,
                (f(std::get<Is>(std::forward<T>(tup))), 0)...
        })
        ;
    }
}

template<typename T, typename F, std::size_t TupSize = std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<T>>>
constexpr auto tuple_foreach(T&& tup, F f) {
    return detail::tuple_foreach(
        std::forward<T>(tup), f,
        std::make_index_sequence<TupSize>{}
    );
}

template<class Set1, class Set2>
auto func(Set1 set1, Set2 set2)
{
    constexpr auto N1 = std::tuple_size<Set1>::value;
    constexpr auto N2 = std::tuple_size<Set2>::value;
    static_assert(N1 == N2, "");

    // now do things with std::get<0 ... N-1>(set1) and
    // std::get<0 ... N-1>(set2);

    using result_type = std::decay_t<decltype(std::get<0>(set1).value())>;

    // let's compute the sum of the inputs
    result_type result = 0;
    tuple_foreach(set1, 
                        [&](auto&& elem)
                        {
                            result += elem.value();
                        });
    tuple_foreach(set2, 
                        [&](auto&& elem)
                        {
                            result += elem.value();
                        });

    return result;
}

void emit(float);

int main()
{
    auto x = func(std::tie(input[4], input[2], input[9]), 
                  std::tie(output[6], output[8], output[1]));
    emit(x);
}
```

assembly emitted with compiler setting `-O2`:

```
main:
  pxor xmm0, xmm0
  sub rsp, 8
  addss xmm0, DWORD PTR input[rip+16]
  addss xmm0, DWORD PTR input[rip+8]
  addss xmm0, DWORD PTR input[rip+36]
  addss xmm0, DWORD PTR output[rip+24]
  addss xmm0, DWORD PTR output[rip+32]
  addss xmm0, DWORD PTR output[rip+4]
  call emit(float)
  xor eax, eax
  add rsp, 8
  ret
```

Can't get much more efficient than that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, whether I get the question, but you can do

```
template<typename... T, int... N>
void func(const Elem<T, N>&... elems)
```

if you want your function to take any number of `Elem<>`. If you need to restrict them to a single `T` (e.g. `Elem<int,>` and `Elem<float,>` may not be passed together), just use

```
template<typename T, int... N>
void func(const Elem<T, N>&... elems)
```

If you need to restrict the number of arguments, just use a

```
static_assert(sizeof...(elems) <= 6, "...");
```

inside the function body. If `N` has to be equal for all elements and the number of arguments should be 2*N, use:

```
template<typename... T, int N>
void func(const Elem<T, N>&... elems) 
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(elems) == 2*N, "invalid number of arguments");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I need two sets of arguments  : 

    template<typename... T, int N>
    void func(const Elem<T, N>&... inputs, const Elem<T,N>&... outputs) 
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(inputs) == N, "invalid number of arguments");
        static_assert(sizeof...(outputs) == N, "invalid number of arguments");
    }

Comment: @user1524126 - I ask to see if I understand correctly: you need `2*N` arguments; the first `N` (input argument) are of type `Elem<T, N> const &` (I mean: same `N` of the number of arguments and `T` equal in every argument) and last `N` are of type `Elem<T, N> &` (every the same `N` and same `T`). Correct?

Comment: @max66 : exactly !

Comment: @user1524126 It is hard to specify these constraints within the function signature. You can, however, enforce them using `static_assert`. I recommend writing a little helper template, which checks that all `T` of the first resp. second half of arguments is equal and use this helper inside a `static_assert`.