# How to distinguish multiple variadic templates

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I would like to define a method which can accept two different variadic types (`A` and `B`) trying to give a hint to the compiler to distinguish them, such as `std::optional<B>`:

```
#include <optional>

template <typename... A, typename... B>
void method(A... a, std::optional<B>&... b)
{
    // ...
};
```

Event when I instantiate `A` and `B` with a different type (for example `bool` and `int` respectively), GNU compiler is still unable to distinguish where `A` finishes and `std::optional<B>` starts:

```
method(true, false, std::optional<int>{0}); // note: candidate template ignored:
                                            // could not match 'std::optional<B>' against 'bool'
```

Is there any way to give a *hint* to the compiler to distinguish these two types?

Comment: Your problem is that an `A` can be anything, including a `std::optional<T>`.  What problem are you actually trying to solve using this?

Comment: Exactly, `A` is included in the definition of `B`. I would to call it like this: `method(bool, bool, bool, std::optional<int>, std::optional<int>);`

Comment: It's not possible to deduce two packs like this. You have to accept `(A&&... a)`, and then filter `a`s individually.

Comment: *"method which can accept two different variadic types..."* C++ doesn't allow this.

Comment: Related/dupe: [C++ Multiple sets of variadic function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176713/c-multiple-sets-of-variadic-function-arguments)

Comment: What version of C++ standard can you use? C++17/C++20 (basically can you use concepts)?

Comment: @MarekR C++17 but I would accept C++20 if it solves this